# How do I read this c# code - Action<object> actDelegateTakeObjAsParam = (Action<object>) (obj => actionImp());

Tags: c#, delegates

Example of something I found in Mvvm code.

```
Action<object> actDelegateTakeObjAsParam = (Action<object>) (obj => actionImp());
```

I think I understand what it does but I'm having trouble with syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
Action<object> actDelegateTakeObjAsParam
```

declare a variable named `actDelegateTakeObjAsParam` of type `Action<object>` (a delegate that takes an `object` and returns `void`, i.e. no return value).

```
= (Action<object>)(obj => actionImp());
```

Assign to it a delegate instance of type `Action<object>`, where the delegate instance takes parameter `obj`, ignores it, and invokes `actionImp()` (whatever that is).

Basically, it looks like it re-wraps a delegate as a different type - maybe `actionImp` is actually `Action`, `ThreadStart` or `MethodInvoker` (all of which are parameterless and don't return a value) or `Func<string>` (parameterless but returns a `string`); this allows the intent of `actionImp` to be used as though it were an `Action<object>`.

Minor note: because `obj` is ignored, recent convention would be to use `_` instead of `obj` as the name, i.e. `_ => actionImp()`

Comment: So, is "(Action<object>)" a cast operation?

Comment: @JohnAldrin, yes. (specifcally, lambda expressions like `x => DoStuff();` themselves are also known as anonymous functions. Casting such a lambda expression to a compatible delegate type produces a delegate of this type, referring to this anonymous function; see also here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions)

Comment: @JohnAldrin, note that the cast here is redundant. The lambda expression can be implicitely converted if the compiler can infer the delegate type for the conversion. Thus, you could also write `Action<object> x = obj => actionImp();`